# Can you set the initial directory in Silverlight's SaveFileDialog

Tags: silverlight, savefiledialog

Can you set the initial directory in Silverlight's SaveFileDialog?  I'm not seeing it as an option.

If you can not set it in code how does Silverlight determines the initial directory.  It looks like it remembers the last location used but is that per silverlight app.  What about initial use of the savefiledialog (maybe the Desktop?)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first time silverlight opens the file dialog (either the open or the save) it will be placed at My Documents (I think its really difficult to test for as you'll see).

After that Silverlight remembers the last folder selected when the dialog was affirmatively closed (a canceled dialog forgets any folder change that may have been made).

The Last folder used memory impacts all usage of Silverlight for that user regardless of application or site as far as I can tell.

There is no way to specify the initial folder from code.